Dress code for examiner in UK PhD viva
I was asked to be an external examiner in a math PhD viva at a UK university. I have never been to a UK defense and cannot find specific regulations/dress code guidelines on the University website.
What is the norm for what you wear in such events as an examiner? Is it usually formal or casual? My overwhelming preference is to wear casual unless that would offend someone. Would that offend someone?

Please do not write answers in the comments. Existing comments have been moved to chat. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. We can only move to chat once, so future comment-answers will be removed.

Can you ask the persons who invite you to this event ?

@Job_September_2020 I could, but then the next person who has the same question can't just Google it and has to ask their host

UK vivas are not generally ceremonial in nature (the ceremony is left for graduation). As such, most people will dress more or less "normally". Especially in mathematics, I would expect most examiners to be dressed in a relatively casual manner.
In essence, treat the viva as an important meeting with fellow academics. I wouldn't recommend wearing shorts and flip-flops but, unless the maths department you are visiting is unusual in this regard, business-formal clothing would probably not be expected.

Depending on circumstances and travel plans, you may be taken out for dinner somewhere after the viva - so a good guideline is to dress as you would for a modestly smart restaurant!

Yeah in my experience examiners would wear whatever they normally wear when teaching, meeting students, etc. (It may depend where you are in the world, but most restaurants have no dress code beyond "no shirt, no shoes, no service".)

Yep, my go to for a viva is dark coloured jeans, a smartish button down shirt and either a fine knit wool sweater or a blazer/sports/tweed jacket and nice trainers.

@avid How can smart be an adjective of a restaurant :)

@ArchismanPanigrahi why can't smart be an adjective relating to a restaurant. The definition includes décor and decorum as would be seen in a restaurant as well as clothing.

@ArchismanPanigrahi https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smart see etymology 2 bullet 4

@ArchismanPanigrahi More specifically (https://www.oed.com/dictionary/smart_adj?tab=meaning_and_use#246505510) "II.13.b. Of a building, vehicle, etc.: neat and pleasing in appearance; clean, bright, well presented or maintained." This is a use that is (I think!) reasonably common in British English but maybe not everywhere.

I did not know this meaning of the word "smart". Thank you for teaching me.

For almost all UK universities, Louwe's answer is  correct. The only exception I am aware of is Oxford¹, where the candidate and internal examiner are expected to wear academic dress (smart clothes and gown). This does not apply to the external examiner, who will often dress as they would for a viva elsewhere in the UK, but if you happen to be examining at Oxford you may wish to be aware of this idiosyncrasy and dress a little more smartly.

¹Cambridge is not like Oxford in this regard

Can verify, last examiner I saw around in Cambridge maths was wearing a hoodie.

My view is that you don't want to make the candidate uncomfortable because they are either dressed too smartly or too casually.  So I tend to be smart-ish, e.g. a suit but perhaps not wearing a tie if they are scruffy.  I prefer not to be smartly dressed if I can help it, but it seems disrespectful to the candidate to turn up scruffy if they are smartly dressed, so I make a bit of an effort.  Note this is a "special" day for the candidate, even if it isn't for you.
(but otherwise I agree with @Louwe, +1)
